# Specify range of rows when using pandas.DataFrame.shift

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to specify a range of rows when using the `pandas.DataFrame.shift` method or is there a similar approach I can use?

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Col1": [True, False, False, True, False], 
     "Col2": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
    index=pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-01-05"))
```

If I want to query current row and previous row I can use the following query:

```
df.query("(Col1 == True) & (Col2 == 2) | (Col1 == True) & (Col2.shift(1) == 2)")
```

What if I also want to see if `Col2.shift(2)` and `Col2.shift(3)` etc `==2` for current row?

Do  need to add more conditions like `| (Col1 == True) & (Col2.shift(2) == 2` or is there a way to specify a range for `shift`

Preference is to use `query` but open to other ways.

Comment: There is no range of shift ~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `rolling.max`.

First, for the boolean condition:

```
(A&B) | (A&C) | ...
```

is equivalent to

```
((A&B) | A) & ((A&B)|C)
```

is equivalent to

```
A & (B|C)
```

You can inductively prove that this holds for any number of conditions, so you can take the condition for "Col1" out of the nesting and chain the "Col2" conditions with `|` and do a single `&` with "Col1", like:

```py
df['Col1'] & ( df['Col2'].eq(2) | df['Col2'].shift(1).eq(2) )
```

Then since you want True to be returned even if a single day has value equal to 2 in the rolling number of days, `max` should suffice.

```py
rng = 2
out = df[df['Col2'].eq(2).rolling(rng).max().fillna(0).astype(bool) & df['Col1']]
```

Output:

```py
            Col1  Col2
2020-01-04  True     3
```